# Please explain the uses of 'be + used to' and 'used to'

Tags: phrase-usage

> 1. He was used to sitting there.
> 2. He used to sit there.

Do they have the same meaning? If not, please explain it to me.

Answer (score 3):

> He was used to sitting there.

The part that says "he was used to" means that he was acclimated to sitting there. Another example of this is "I am used to eating spicy food". This means that I am comfortable/acclimated to eating spicy food.

> He used to sit there

This means that at one time he would sit there. This implies that he does not sit there anymore.